# How to summarize the total number of products

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

I created a field in opportunity, i need to get the total number of quantity of the products whenever I add or delete a product. As much as possible I want to avoid triggers. Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new field
2. Type **Roll-Up Summary**
3. Name it
4. Select **Opportunity products** as the roll up object
5. Select `SUM`
6. Select Quantity as the field

This will give you the "total number of quantity of the products" as outlined in your question